# MATLAB 2-Layer Neural Network from Scratch

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation

Currently, I'm working on a simple two Layer NN (25 input - sigmoid, 199 outputs - softmax) from scratch for debug reasons - Precisely, I want to track some values.

My input are batches or generally speaking matrices of dimension (rows x 25) in order to fit the input layer structure. Regarding my weight matrices: the first but last rows are the weights w_ij. The last row includes the biases.

The forward method seems to work correctly but I think I have a wrong backpropagation.

My backpropagation code snippet:

```
%Error gradient for the softmax output
error = single(output) - single(targets);

%Error for the input layer - W21 includes w_ij
error_out_to_input = error*(W21.');

gradient_outputLayer = single(zeros(26,199));
gradient_outputLayer = single(first_layerout_zerofilled.')*single(error);

biasGrad = single(sum(error,1));
gradient_outputLayer(26:26,:) = single(biasGrad);

%InputLayer

%derivative of sigmoid  o(1-o) 

%1
grad = single(1);
%1-o
grad = single(grad) - single(first_layerout_zerofilled);
%o(1-o)
grad = single(first_layerout_zerofilled) .* single((grad));

%final error
grad = single(grad) .* single(error_out_to_input);


gradient_inputLayer = single(zeros(26,25));
gradient_inputLayer = single(inputs.')*single(grad);

biasGrad = single(sum(grad,1));
gradient_inputLayer(26:26,:) = single(biasGrad);


%Update
W1 = W1-gradient_inputLayer  * learning_rate;
W2 = W2-gradient_outputLayer * learning_rate;
```

This is not a question of efficiency. I just want to be sure that my backprogation calculates the correct gradients. I hope someone can review.